# Update Ingress after Upgrading Kubernetis cluster version

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, nginx-ingress

I've got 2 k8 clusters on `1.19` and `1.16` versions.
It's need to be updated to `1.22`. And from documentation I found that Ingress API changed for `1.22` (`extensions/v1beta1` deprecated)

Cluster contains allot of ingress with `extensions/v1beta1` API. How I can update them during k8 upgrade process?

Answer (score 1):

Before version *1.20* there was `kubectl convert` command, which was used to [convert to non-depracted APIs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#migrate-to-non-deprecated-apis). However, it was removed in *1.20* <sup>[[reference](https://github.com/aws/aws-eks-best-practices/issues/121)]</sup>, and now lives as a plugin for `kubectl`.

Instructions on how to install this plugin are available [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-kubectl-convert-plugin).

You have to update your manifest files with `kubectl convert`, and reapply them with `kubectl apply`.

As of today, there is no other way to update resources to newer API versions.